# SSDT does not publish column COLLATION change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

It seems that SSDT does not publish column COLLATION, even though it detects a change during comparison process.

An issue appears that if you change a column COLLATION on a specific column in a table, and try to publish the change, the SSDT will ignore it when creating a publish script.

Here is a similar issue described on [msdn forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/042ec6d6-b212-45fc-bf05-9ecab35bff1a/ssdt-not-publishing-column-collation-change?forum=ssdt), detected long ago, that is still reproduced.

I have been using SSDT version 14.0.60629.0
Does the SSDT still have this issue, or is there a valid workaround?

**Update**
This issue is  only for the columns which are using a User-Defined Data Type.

**Update**
 (added steps to reproduce, and corrected the question text):

Steps to reproduce: 
1. Start with a database and note the collations
(this is the one I have, a DB on my Dev server):

Current COLLATION setup is:

- Server
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- Database
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- Table
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- User-Defined Data Type (dt_Source AS varchar(20))
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- Column (Source AS dt_source)
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

2.Then change the database collation.

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [<db_name>] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CS_AS
```

New COLLATION setup will be:

- Server
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- Database
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CS_AS
- Table
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CS_AS
- User-Defined Data Type (dt_Source AS varchar(20))
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1250_CS_AS
- Column (Source AS dt_source)
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Previous column collation (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) will remain, and SSDT Compare mechanism will not be able to detect any change.

This will lead to an error message, if I try to create a Foreign Key constraint on this column, referencing another, newly populated column, in another table, because the Publish Script from Comparison was built without knowing the true collation.
For, example, this produces an error, because column collations are different:

```
ALTER TABLE [FCT].[Inventory] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Inventory_Source] FOREIGN KEY ([Source]) REFERENCES [DIM].[Source] ([SourceCode]);
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior that you've described using the latest version of SSDT and there were no bug fixes in this area post-14.0.60629.0 (I'm on the team).  Have you verified that the "Ignore Column Collation" publish option is not selected?  If so, could you provide an example table schema (before and after) that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: I have updated the question, addding steps to reproduce. Also, I have noted that this only happens for columns using User-Defined Data Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you ENABLE "script database collation" in the publish settings (tab: general)
source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128002/ssdt-publish-window-what-does-checkbox-enable-mean

then it might take multiple publications
first it does on db level, later on table/column level